# NodeJS + mongoose await for subquery

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have two models: `ModelA` and `ModelB`, I am trying to copy a `tags = Array()` column from `ModelB` into `ModelA`, like this:

```
function run() {

  ModelA.find({}).limit(500).cursor()
    .on('data', function(doc) {
      let refID = doc.ref_id;

      ModelB.findOne({_id: refID}).exec(function(err, modelb) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(`[Error]: Getting modelb ${refID}`);
        }
        if (modelb) {
          if (modelb.tags.length > 0) {
            doc.tags = modelb.tags;
          }
        }
      });

      doc.processed = true;
      doc.save(function(err, hackAlert) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('[Error]: Saving ModelA: ' + err);
        }
        console.log(`Saved: ${doc._id}`);
      });
    })
    .on('error', function(err){
      console.log('[Error]');
    })
    .on('end', function(){
      console.log('Done');
    });
}
```

The script obviously saves all `ModelA` instances with `processed = true` but given the asynchronous nature of Node, `ModelA` documents end up without `tags`.

I'm new to this if you can't tell. I wanted to know what is the best, modern way to `"await"` for the `ModelB.findOne()` query to finish before saving `ModelA` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply move the code to be called on the callback of your first query:

```
function run() {

  ModelA.find({}).limit(500).cursor()
    .on('data', function(doc) {
      let refID = doc.ref_id;

      ModelB.findOne({_id: refID}).exec(function(err, modelb) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(`[Error]: Getting modelb ${refID}`);
        }
        if (modelb) {
          if (modelb.tags.length > 0) {
            doc.tags = modelb.tags;
          }
        }
        doc.processed = true;
        doc.save(function(err, hackAlert) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('[Error]: Saving ModelA: ' + err);
          }
          console.log(`Saved: ${doc._id}`);
        });
      });
    })
    .on('error', function(err){
      console.log('[Error]');
    })
    .on('end', function(){
      console.log('Done');
    });
}
```

For a more up-to-date approach using `async/await` and `Promises`:

```
async function run () {

  ModelA.find({}).limit(500).cursor()
    .on('data', async function (doc) {
      let refID = doc.ref_id;
      const modelb = await ModelB.findOne({_id: refID}).exec()
        .catch(() => console.log(`[Error]: Getting modelb ${refID}`));

      if (modelb) {
        if (modelb.tags.length > 0) {
          doc.tags = modelb.tags;
        }
      }
      doc.processed = true;
      await doc.save().exec()
        .catch(err => console.log('[Error]: Saving ModelA: ' + err))

      console.log(`Saved: ${doc._id}`);
    })
    .on('error', function (err){
      console.log('[Error]');
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('Done');
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks I was looking something like your second approach, the first approach does not fit me because `findOne` might not find any related documents and I still need to save `ModelA` document with `processed=true`. Appreciate your help

Comment: No problem! First approach should also update the document, as the `callback` should get executed anyways, but the second one is cleaner.